# Why I get error message "Invalid number" since UserID is NUMBER

Tags: string, oracle, datetime, plsql, where-clause

I am little bit confusing and have no idea where I made mistake.

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
WHERE uta.UserID = 353
AND uta.Approved = 'true'
AND '2020-03-06' BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

In following query I get error

```
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

I try to understand where the error is, but when I realize query a deeper I can not see where the error is.

```
ABSENCETYPE VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
ANSWER  VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)
APPROVED    NUMBER(10,0)
COMMENT_    CLOB
DAYS    NUMBER(10,0)
ENDDATE VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
ISANSWERED  NUMBER(10,0)
ISREJECTED  NUMBER(10,0)
STARTDATE   VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
USERABSENCEID   NUMBER(10,0)
USERHASSEEN VARCHAR2(500 CHAR)
USERID  NUMBER(10,0)
WIDTH   NUMBER(10,0)
```

When I insert data into table, I use this kind of data and It works fine. But when I use SELECT statment I get error. I hope the error was UserID but it wasn't.

```
Insert into DB.USER_TIMESHEETS_ABSENCE (ABSENCETYPE,ANSWER,APPROVED,DAYS,ENDDATE,ISANSWERED,ISREJECTED,STARTDATE,USERABSENCEID,USERHASSEEN,USERID,WIDTH) values ('1','ne',0,8,'2020-02-06',1,1,'2020-01-30',89,'1',348,160);
```

Can someone tell me, where I made mistake ? What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more than one problem in this query.

Firstly, here:

```
AND uta.Approved = 'true'
```

`approved` is a number, but you are comparing it against string 'true'. This does not work. Use a literal number on the right side of the equal sign.

Then, here:

```
AND '2020-03-06' 
    BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

You are comparing a string against dates. This won't work. You probably want a literal date on the left side of `between`. I would also recommend using `+ 1` rather than the interval syntax, which should be reserved to `timestamp`s:

```
AND DATE '2020-03-06' 
    BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + 1
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer :) I get where the error is now :) I get the point :D

Comment: @GMB Do you have anything authoritative (or close) about not adding intervals to dates?

Comment: I too would be interested to know why you think the INTERVAL arithmetic should be reserved for timestamps. The Oracle documentation suggests that dates are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @APC: I remember reading that more than once here in SO, but can't find an actual reference, and the documentation indeed tends to [state otherwise](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705). So you probably are right about the fact that using intervals and date is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why are STARTDATE and ENDDATE defined as strings rather than `date`. Not using the correct data types is a surefire way to introduce data corruption issues. That's certainly where I would start looking.

The other thing is, always use explicit casting when converting strings into dates (or numbers) and vice versa. In this case you should use a date literal. Instead of

```
AND '2020-03-06' BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

use

```
AND date '2020-03-06' BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

If you have got data corruption in your date columns and you're on 12c or later you can use VALIDATE_CONVERSATION to filter rows which don't contain valid dates:

```
SELECT uta.StartDate, uta.EndDate FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
WHERE uta.UserID = 353
AND uta.Approved = 'true'
AND validate_conversion(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 1
AND validate_conversion(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 1 
AND date '2020-03-06' BETWEEN TO_DATE(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

You can also use this to find invalid date strings:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_timesheets_absence uta
WHERE validate_conversion(uta.StartDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 0
OR validate_conversion(uta.EndDate,'YYYY-MM-DD') = 0
```

Comment: Interesting. @GMB has a valid point regarding `AND uta.Approved = 'true'`